# show only max date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get order no 1628481 output showing for 2999-01-01. I am using the `Group By` command and the aggregate function `MAX()` for Date and it shows all rows.

[image]

Comment: order from greatest date to less date with limit 1 to get the first row that is the max date.

Comment: Are you trying to get the row with the max date having the PUK 1628481 ?

Comment: Which database product are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: if you want max enddate per PUK only, then you have to remove all of your other columns.  Right now, you've asked for the max enddate per all of the columns included in your group by clause- puk, material, statusID, substatusID, and statusReasonUID, which is what it returned.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell exactly what your primary key is, but that is the only thing missing from the code.

```
Select s.*
From dbo.PUK_Status s
INNER JOIN (
SELECT [Whatever the PK is], MAX(ENDDATE) maxdate
from PUK_STATUS 
WHERE PUK = '1628481'
) maxs
on s.[Whatever the PK is] = maxs.[Whatever the PK is]
and s.ENDDATE = maxs.ENDDATE
```